Two-Dimensional Wave Equation and Nodal Lines
I'm struggling with this question regarding the nodal lines of a 2D wave equation on a rectangular membrane. So I'm given the following equation:
$u_{tt}-c^2(u_{xx}+u_{yy})=0, (x,y,t)\in R\times[0,\infty),$
$u(x,y,t)=0, (x,y,t)\in\partial R\times[0,\infty),$
$u(x,y,0)=\phi(x,y), u_t(x,y,0)=\psi(x,y), (x,y)\in\bar{R}$
Where $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0<x<a,0<y<b\}$ and $\bar{R}$ is the closure of $R$.
By using separation of variables, I derived a series solution to the equation:
$u(x,y,t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[A_{m,n}\mathrm{cos}(\lambda_{m,n}ct)+B_{m,n}\mathrm{sin}(\lambda_{m,n}ct)\right]\mathrm{sin}(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{m\pi}{b}y)$, where
$A_{m,n}=\frac{4}{ab}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{b}\phi(x,y)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{m\pi}{b}y)dydx$,
$B_{m,n}=\frac{4}{abc\lambda_{m,n}}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{b}\psi(x,y)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{m\pi}{b}y)dydx$
The question I am struggling to answer is as follows:

Find any pair of functions $\phi,\psi$ such that the function $u(x,y,t)$ is non-trivial and has nodal lines at $x=a/2$ and at $y=b/2$

I understand that nodal lines are lines where the displacement of the function is zero for all values of time, which to me implies that we want to look at where $\mathrm{sin}(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)\mathrm{sin}(\frac{m\pi}{b}y)=0$, but I'm quite unsure how to approach this problem.
Thanks!

A possible pair is $\phi(x,y)=C\sin(2\pi x/a)\sin(2\pi y/b)$, $\psi(x,y)=0$.
